# How to keep repository classes lean?

Tags: design-patterns, repository, repository-pattern

I have been reading a lot on repositories, generic repositories, UoW etc and alternatives. It seems that everyone has an opinion about them. Some say not to use generic repos as it is an unnecessary abstraction. Others says UoW is is also an unneeded abstraction. Some folks say to put common functionality into a base class and the repo can inherit from it.

I am wondering what is the best way to keep repositories light and lean - that is avoiding a proliferation of  highly specialized queries like FindAllOrdersFromTwoYearsAgoFromAlaska?

One option as i see it is to return IQueryables and do any additional filtering in the service layer

Also it seems like query commands is another way to avoid things like that above query from happening. Just looking for some guidance on keeping the repos light and lean.

Hopefully this does not get closed as being one of those opinion based threads.

Comment: I fail to see the point of avoiding specialized methods in the DAOs. IMHO, the 3 main goals of the DAO are to isolate the Data access logic from the services (which is not the case anymore if the service has to build the query filter), to make the services easily testable by mocking the DAOs (which is not as easily doable if the DAO only has generic methods), and to make the data access logic easily testable (which is not the case anymore if you have to rebuild the query filters in your tests to make sure they work correctly when actually executed by the DAO)

Comment: @JBNizet, what if the business rule goes something like this: Cannot delete a document if it is not six months or older. In this case I would rather have the service layer build the query filter because it is tied up with the logic, instead of passing the logic to a specialize method in the repository.

Comment: @Ronald in that case, all you need in the DAO is a findById() method. The service will call it, see if it's older than 6 months, and delete it or not. But yes, DAO methods are written in order to participate in the business logic, otherwise, they would be useless. They just implement the data access part of this logic only.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need it, there is always the [Query Object Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html)  This is the pattern used by Hibernate's Criteria Queries.

```
OrderQuery query = new OrderQueryBuilder()
                          .whereDate(from(2012))
                          .whereLocation(eq("Alaska"))
                          .build();

Stream<Order> orders = orderRepository.findAllThatMatch(query);
```

However, it is rarely ever needed unless you need to do a lot of ad-hoc queries.  Look at all the code you would have to write to just support this one query!  It's usually better from a effort point of view, to just add more methods to your repository.